# Nginx configuration for a PHP custom file handler

Tags: nginx, php

I am new to nginx and am learning as I go. I have the following nginx configuration for a blog site I'm trying out. When I go to my site http://example.org/markdown-example.md, it loads the content of the md file on the page instead of passing it on to md.php.

Can someone please advise on what I might be doing wrong? Thank you!

```
file: /etc/nginx/sites-available/blog

# pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri  =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini

    # With php5-cgi alone:
    # fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    # With php5-fpm:
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
}


location ~ \.md$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $document_root;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $uri;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /usr/share/nginx/blog/md.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
}

location ~ ^(.*)\.md/raw$ {
    try_files $1.md =404;
}
```

I've also added .md as one of the allowed file extensions:

```
file: /etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf
security.limit_extensions = .md .php .php3 .php4 .php5
```

Additionally when I go to http://example.org/markdown-example.md/raw, the .md file gets downloaded for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A more appropriate way of doing what you want is to make you `location ~ \.md$` block like this:

```
location ~ \.md$ {
    rewrite ^ /blog/md.php last;
}
```

Here I assume that your `root` directive is specified to be `/usr/share/nginx/`, so that the `rewrite` will resolve to `/usr/share/nginx/blog/md.php`

So, this rewrite will redirect the request to any path ending with `.md` to md.php. After this rewrite, nginx will perform another round of matching, and it will find the `location ~ \.php$` block, which it then uses to pass the script execution to the PHP engine.

Comment: Sorry that doesn't work. Rewrite only redirects to /blog/md.php. I want to process http://example.org/markdown-example.md using md.php and then display the output of that on the page. md.php takes in the $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] as relative path of markdown-example.md and converts it into html.

Comment: You should modify `md.php` to use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` instead of `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'].

Comment: Since I'm debugging, I'm reading the $_SERVER variables in md.php and echoing as follows:
`DOCUMENT_ROOT=/usr/share/nginx/blog
SCRIPT_NAME=/md.php
SCRIPT_FILENAME=/usr/share/nginx/blog/md.php
REQUEST_URI=/md.php`

Comment: Ahh, I think I had an additional / in one place. Thanks for your help! :)